# Automorphisms of the Upper Half Plane $f(z)=2z$

Tags: complex-analysis

I see the following theorem which characterizes the set of automorphisms of the upper half plane:

Every automorphism $f$ of the upper half plane is of the form 
$$
f(z)=\frac{a z+b}{c z+d}
$$
where $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{R} \text { and } a d-b c=1$.

My question is: $f(z)=2z$ is an automorphism but it can not be written as
$$
f(z)=\frac{a z+b}{c z+d}
$$
where $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{R} \text { and } a d-b c=1$. Am I wrong?

Comment: $2z=\frac{\frac{2}{\sqrt 2}z+0}{0z+\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}}$.

Comment: @YuDing got it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is more convenient to just require reals and $ad-bc>0.$ To get $1,$ your case uses $a=\sqrt 2,$ $d = 1/\sqrt 2,$ $b=c=0$

Comment: I see. Thank you very much!